# get_post_metadata() undefined when used in loop in RSS template

Tags: templates, rss, post-meta

I understand *how* to use `get_post_metadata()`, however this code in a custom RSS feed template:

```
while( have_posts()) : the_post();

    // Has a custom URL been supplied? Use that in preference.
    $feature_permalink = ‌‌get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_featureurl', true);

    [...]
```

is giving:

> HP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   ‌‌get_post_meta() in
>   /srv/www/foo/htdocs/wp-content/themes/bar/feed-feature.php

(and indeed the PhpStorm editor highlights it accordingly, but with an xdebug breakpoint set, I can run it fine in the debug console.  All the other various feed function calls - for the standard permalink, title, guid etc. - work fine.)

The template is in `functions.php`, called with:

```
function foo_custom_rss() {
    if ( in_array('feature', get_query_var('post_type')) ) {
        get_template_part( 'feed', 'feature' );
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'feed', 'rss2' );
    }
}

remove_all_actions( 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'foo_custom_rss', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to add/modify on the feature post type's RSS2 feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround, but it did solve things for me.

First I moved this site from my vvv to vvv2 dev environment, to rule out anything odd there. Then I went through the WP config files and the rest of functions.php carefully looking for anything with the potential to break things.

No luck so far.

I traced *get_post_meta()* in the source, thinking I might only be able to solve this by rewriting an equivalent function myself (creating a DB query if necessary) - as readers may know it's simply a wrapper for [get_metadata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/) - for some reason this *does* work.

So if anyone can suggest why get_post_meta() is undefined and get_metadata() isn't...

Answer (score 1):

To modify an RSS item's `<link>` node value, use the `the_permalink_rss` filter. This is demonstrated in the code below where if a `feature` post has a value set for `_featureurl`, we will return the custom value. Otherwise, the default permalink is returned:

```
/**
 * Filters the permalink to the post for use in feeds.
 *
 * @param string $post_permalink The current post permalink.
 */
add_filter( 'the_permalink_rss', 'wpse_the_permalink_rss', 10, 1 );
function wpse_the_permalink_rss( $post_permalink ) {
    // Bail if this is not a feature.
    if ( 'feature' !== get_query_var( 'post_type') ) {
        return $post_permalink;
    }

    // Get the permalink URL.
    $feature_permalink = get_post_meta( 
            get_the_ID(),
            '_featureurl',
            true 
    );

    // If the the custom URL has been specified return it, otherwise, use default permalink.
    // Note: This is run through esc_url() via the_permalink_rss().
    if ( $feature_permalink  ) {
        return $feature_permalink; 
    } else {
        return $post_permalink;     
    }
}
```

Example RSS output for the `feature` post type, which has the following URL:

`http://example.com/feed/?post_type=feature`

Note that the `<link>` node under the `<item>` node contains the URL `https://google.com`, which is what I set for the `_featureurl` custom field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    >

<channel>
    <title>Features &#8211; WP Theme Testing</title>
    <atom:link href="http://localhost/wp-theme-testing/feed/?post_type=feature" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>http://localhost/wp-theme-testing</link>
    <description>I &#60;3 testing themes!</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Sun, 04 Mar 2018 05:46:16 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
    <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.9.1</generator>

<image>
    <url>http://localhost/wp-theme-testing/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/cropped-favicon-32x32.png</url>
    <title>Features &#8211; WP Theme Testing</title>
    <link>http://localhost/wp-theme-testing</link>
    <width>32</width>
    <height>32</height>
</image> 
    <item>
        <title>test feature</title>
        <link>https://google.com</link>


        <comments>http://localhost/wp-theme-testing/feartures/test-feature/#respond</comments>
        <pubDate>Sun, 04 Mar 2018 05:41:29 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[dave]]></dc:creator>

        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://localhost/wp-theme-testing/?post_type=feature&#038;p=3035</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[a test!]]></description>
                <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>a test!</p>
]]></content:encoded>
            <wfw:commentRss>http://localhost/wp-theme-testing/feartures/test-feature/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
        <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Hello - thanks. I should clarify, I’m not adding a new node, only changing the value of the permalink if the post has that custom post meta value set.  I did actually take a direct copy of feed-rss2.php and drop it in my theme folder (renamed), but I can’t call get_post_meta() in it for some reason, if you’ve any idea why that might be..

Comment: Hi and thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer. The values of the default nodes can be manipulated using various filters.  `get_post_meta()` can be used within callbacks attached to these filters or within the `rss2_item()` action. If `get_post_meta()` is called within the RSS template directly, it will trigger an error because that portion of WP has not been loaded at that point.

Comment: This all makes sense (and I've up-voted) however I still get undefined for `get_post_meta()` when it's used in functions.php...

Comment: Hrmm, I think something is wrong on your end. I tested this code before posting it and it works. I added the output example to my answer. Try clearing your browser's cache and removing the `foo_custom_rss()` related code from your theme.